# Different ways to prepare 5 dishes

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

There are 3 entities of ingredient A, 8 of ingredient B, 12 of C and 7 of D.

Person $P_3$ may consume his dish iif it contains an even number of ingredients. Person $P_4$ requires that his dish contains at least 2 entities of ingredient B and person $P_1$ wants that if his dish contains any number of A's, then it contains exactly as much C's. Persons $P_2$ and $P_5$ have no special preferences.

In how many different ways may one cook dishes for all? (a dish contains at least 1 ingredient)

This problem is giving me one hell of a time. I know I must utilise the inclusion exclusion principle but I am really stuck.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited the question - persons are P1-P5 so that it is clear to distinguish them from the ingredients. It was a typo - P3 has preference, P2 and P5 do not

Comment: P3 requires an "even number of ingredients". So P3 must have at least one ingredient of each type (A,B,C,D) or at least one of each of two types and none of the other two? Or does it mean an even number of entities? ie could P3 have (i) 2 As and 3 Bs, or (ii) 2 As, 2 Bs and 4 Cs?

Comment: P3 requires "even number of ingredients in total". E.g 1A+1B; 2B+1D+1D; 2A;
@almagest